# Google Ads Optimization Score - Get via API or other method

Tags: javascript, api, web-scraping, google-ads-api

I would like to daily monitor the optimization score of Google Ads.
It is the metric shown below on the printscreen.

Does anyone know a method ( via API, Supermetrics, or other script ) to return this value to a Google Spreadsheet?
I've been searching on Google Ads API but did not find anything so far, and I am curious if anyone got a solution for this.

[image: Google Ads print with Optimization Score]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get the optimization score for an account or campaign in the latest version of the API: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v4/Campaign#optimization_score

You access it the same way you access any other resource of the API. I believe Supermetrics has it now too as a result. If you need some help with querying the API, let me know and I can do up a query, but the implementation will depend on your own setup.